# Could this recursive binary search algorithm be more efficient?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, binary-search

I've seen a lot of different implementations of this algorithm, but I'm wondering if there are ways to improve the efficiency beyond just making the search binary.  I've designed this particular version of the algorithm so the edges and midpoint of an array/list will be checked immediately for the key being searched for, as to avoid looping through a search when the key your looking for is just the first, middle, or last element.

```
def searchRB(the_array, the_key, imin, imax):
    print("searching")
    found = False
    if (0 > the_key or the_key > len(the_array)):
        return found
    else:
        imid = imin + ((imax - imin) // 2)
        if imid == the_key or imin == the_key or imax == the_key:
            found = True
            return found
        elif the_array[imid] > the_key:
            return searchRB(the_array, the_key, imin, imid-1)
        elif the_array[imid] < the_key:
            return searchRB(the_array, the_key, imid+1, imax)
        else:
            return found
```

For example, if your were looking for the number 1 in a list of 1-100, this would find it on the first loop, unlike some other implementations.

However, I'm not sure if this actually improves efficiency at all (except for certain edge cases), and if checking the first, mid, and end values in the list/array is actually detrimental once you continue to loop and have to check those three values every time.

Is this is good or bad implementation of this type of algorithm, or am I just splitting hairs?

Comment: Iterative binary search will be more efficient.

Comment: Interesting, could you elaborate a little on why that is?

Comment: how would you start the search? what are the values for the_key, imin, imax?

Comment: the_key = the number you're searching for, imin = the min value in the range your searching, imax = the max value in the range your searching.

Comment: Does this work? Shouldn't you be checking if the_array[imid] == the_key instead of just imid?

Comment: Because an iterative implementation avoids the overhead of more function calls, which in Python aren't blazingly fast. I think this is splitting hairs, yes: asymptotically (as size of `the_array` gets large), recognizing the endpoints quickly doesn't benefit. The number of possible endpoints is quite small compared to the number of elements, so you waste extra time on the average element checking for a rare case. Also, the `found` variable isn't useful: just return `False`, `True` and `False` (respectively) where you now return `found`, and delete the two lines `found = <bool-const>`.

Comment: Furthermore, your test for "found it" is wrong: you're testing whether the key IS the midpoint or either endpoint; you mean to test whether `the_array[imid] == the_key` and not `imid == the_key` (!!!) With that change, the second `elif` *becomes* the `else` case: if key isn't equal to or greater than the value at the midpoint, then it has nowhere else to go.

Comment: Yeah, you're both right about the `imid == the_key`.  It should be `the_array[imid] == the_key`

Comment: We'll call that a typo :) PS: Tried to correct my previous comment but > 5 mins has passed. Last sentence should say "less than" not "greater than".

Comment: If the second `elif` becomes the `else` statement, where would I return the `false` bool? (Assuming I had removed the `found` variable, which makes sense)

Comment: Ah yeah, that's pretty obvious.  I love deleting code I don't need...

Comment: Return False at the top, in the base case of obvious failure: more on that in a minute... Following that, the logic is: if (found-key-at-midpoint), return True; elif key < val-at-midpoint, return searchRB(<left-half>); else return searchRB(<right-half>). Comments don't allow nice formatting, so I hope that's coherent :) 
ANOTHER PROBLEM: The base case test is wrong -- again you're comparing key against indexes and not values. `if (0 > the_key or the_key > len(the_array)): return False` will not work.  Instead, just return `False` if `imin > imax` (slice of `the_array` is empty). (Maybe >= ?)

Comment: Lol :) Um, yeah. At this point, things are broken in pieces on the floor, so when you reassemble them, be sure to test the resulting function. And perhaps post v2 as another question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main big one is changing from recursive approach to using a while loop, saves having a call stack (since python doesn't have tail recursion).

You have small redundancies that can be optimised.
Algorithm already optimised enough, don't [over optimise](https://nopointerexception.wordpress.com/2015/07/16/optimizers-anonymous-1st-step-is-admitting-you-probably-dont-have-a-problem/) unless you understand the compiler

If you're going down the tree on the left you'll be comparing the same imin over and over, however this whole line might be parallelised or done sequentially

`if the_array[imid] == the_key or the_array[min] == the_key or the_array[imax] == the_key:`

Also this could mess with cache performance as you will be have the_array[min] always being kept in cache. Sometimes compilers store a chunk from an array around the index you're trying to access in cache. 
You might be wasting even more cache than just for that 1 value.

Also statements like this could be optimized , you could just type return True , but again this should be picked up by the compiler.

`found = True
return found`

Not having `found` as an object would optimise the code because that object wouldn't be stored in memory the whole time.

This else statement seems redundant as there's no possible way to get to that else
`else
return found`

Actual relevant optimisations will come from knowing more about the dataset.

If you are able to preprocess the data (or have more information about the data) you can do other algorithms.

Comment: One thing I noticed here is that searching the min, max values for equivalence to the key doesn't work very well.  Like you said, the way I was doing it just compares the same min and max values every time it loops (which is useless), but if you use `the_key == the_array[imin] or the_key == the_array[imax]`, the index goes out of range.  I think it's best to just drop it completely, and compare the key to the midpoint only.

Comment: Yea just compare the midpoint and also I think your logic for when to break  is a bit broken, it should be comparing mid with 0 and the length of the array to determine if the index is within bound

Comment: Should define `imid` at the beginning of the function and that statement should be `if 0 > imid or imid > len(the_array):` like you said.